# console.log возвращает undefined

Tags: javascript

Console.log выводит нужные мне данные, но в конце почему то добавляет undefined, инспектор пишет что Undefined выходит на 16 строке, то-есть на вызове консоли.

```js
function fizzBuzz(begin, end) {
  let i = begin;
  while (i <= end) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 != 0) {
      console.log('Fizz')
    } else if (i % 5 === 0 && i % 3 != 0) {
      console.log('Buzz')
    } else if (i % 5 === 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
      console.log('FizzBuzz')
    } else console.log(i)
    i++
  }
}

fizzBuzz(0, 100);
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Сделал ваш пример запускаемым и не вижу никаких `undefined`. Что вы делаете чтобы его получить?

Comment: Если вы запускаете свой код в javascript-консоли, то она всегда показывает последнее вычисленное выражение, а так как ваша функция `fizzBuzz` ничего не возвращает, то и результат вычисления выражения получается undefined. Просто не обращайте на это внимания

Comment: Спасибо за ответ